# Android clipboard manager loop?

Tags: android, clipboard

I am working on personal clipboard app for my phone (because I can :P) and my app crashes if there is nothing on the clipboard. I added a switch/case to see if it defeats that but it does not. I am wanting to have my program run in the background and have it display toast message each time I copy to the clipboard. Now, I have tried using while loop with if statement but still no luck. This is what I have so far.

Edit; Fixed the crash issue, I put the clipboard service inside the switch/case statement, my problem will be just showing toast message every time I copy text.

```
package com.example.copytoclipboard;

import android.R;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);

        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);


        switch(R.id.copy){
        case R.id.copy:
            ClipboardManager clipboard = 
            (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData abc = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
            ClipData.Item item = abc.getItemAt(0);
            String text = item.getText().toString();

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            break;
        }
        }

      }
```

Comment: "and my app crashes" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: commonsware, I figured out why it crashed, I updated my code.

Comment: In order for your app to know when the clipboard data changes, you will need to implement the OnPrimaryClipChangedListener interface of ClipboardManager. If you want your app to constantly be running in the background, you're going to need to create a Service.

Comment: Forgot to update my SO but I fogured it out abd added the primaryclipchanged listener.